# TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str JSON Scrapy

Tags: json, scrapy

I was scraping a JSON response but getting the following error

```
values = resp['acf']
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

I am not sure where did I do wrong.
Your response is highly appreciated.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import scrapy
import json
    
class MainSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'main'
    start_urls = 'https://chamber.vinylagency.com/wp-json/wp/v2/directory?industry-type=547&per_page=100'

    def parse(self, response):
        resp = json.loads(response.body)
        values = resp['acf']
        
        for value in values:
            name = value['OrgName']

            yield {
                "Name": name,
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exception is raised because the response is a list of objects and you are trying to access it as a dict directly.

Here is a sample of the response:

```
[
    {
        "id": 33286,
        "date": "2020-05-09T02:38:47",
        "date_gmt": "2020-05-09T02:38:47",
        "guid":
        ...
    },
    {
        "id": 32954,
        "date": "2020-05-09T02:38:22",
        "date_gmt": "2020-05-09T02:38:22",
        "guid":
        ...
    }
]
```

You probably want to parse like this:

```
def parse(self, response):
    resp = json.loads(response.body)
   
    for value in values:
        name = value['acf']['OrgName']

        yield {
            "Name": name,
        }
```